# Can't get WORKDAY function to work with a COUNTIF

Tags: worksheet-function, countif, excel-2016

Trying to work on a system at work that will tell how many error codes were registered by a particular machine on the previous workday. This spreadsheet will need to be able to select only the errors generated on the previous date as this will become a rolling list of data generated across a wide time span. Currently working with  the formula

```
=TODAY(),-1,B2:B17)
```

where the last array is some shutdown days I've put in to generate a global variable "Yesterday" and trying to use the formula

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[DateOnly],"="&Yesterday)
```

to gather the number of records that occurred yesterday.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Add a tag for the spreadsheet you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was when I tried to convert the timestamp in mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss format to mm/dd/yy and didn't realize that the other information was still hiding in there and confusing the formula. One of my coworkers recommended the use of a ROUNDDOWN function in the use of `=ROUNDDOWN(argument,0)` to get rid of the time information and just leave me with date.